# magento added product programmatically dosent contain the right values

Tags: php, magento, attributes

This is my code of the programmatically  added attribute:

```
<?php                                                                                                                                                

/** @var $installer Welance_DBSetup_Model_Resource_Setup */                                                                                          
$installer = $this;                                                                                                                                  
$installer->startSetup();                                                                                                                            

//NJ add product attributes                                                                                                                          
$attributeId = $installer->getAttributeId('catalog_product','otb_verpackungseinheit');                                                               
if($attributeId){                                                                                                                                    
    $installer->removeAttribute('catalog_product',$attributeId);                                                                                     
}                                                                                                                                                    

$installer->addAttribute('catalog_product', 'otb_verpackungseinheit', array(                                                                         




        'is_global'                     => '1',                                                                                                      
        'frontend_input'                => 'text',                                                                                                   
        'label'                         => 'Verpackungseinheit',                                                                                     
        'is_visible_on_front'           => '1',                                                                                                      
        'used_in_product_listing'       => 'true',                                                                                                   
        'default_value_text'            => '',                                                                                                       
        'default_value_yesno'           => '0',                                                                                                      
        'default_value_date'            => '',                                                                                                       
        'default_value_textarea'        => '',                                                                                                       
        'is_unique'                     => '0',                                                                                                      
        'is_required'                   => '0',                                                                                                      
        'frontend_class'                => '',                                                                                                       
        'is_searchable'                 => '1',                                                                                                      
        'is_visible_in_advanced_search' => '1',                                                                                                      
        'is_comparable'                 => '1',                                                                                                      
        'is_html_allowed_on_front'      => '1',                                                                                                      
        'is_used_for_promo_rules'       => '0',                                                                                                      
        'used_for_sort_by'              => '0',                                                                                                      
        'is_configurable'               => '0',                                                                                                      
        'is_filterable'                 => '0',                                                                                                      
        'is_filterable_in_search'       => '0',                                                                                                      
        'backend_type'                  => 'varchar',                                                                                                
        'default_value'                 => '',                                                                                                       

    )                                                                                                                                                
);                                                                                                                                                   
$installer->updateAttribute('catalog_product', 'otb_verpackungseinheit', 'apply_to', 'configurable,simple,grouped,bundle,virtual,downloadable');     


$installer->endSetup();
```

the attribute appears, and these values are set right:

```
'is_global'                     => '1',
'frontend_input'                => 'text',
'label'                 => 'Verpackungseinheit',
```

but these values remain 0 when i look up the attribute in the backend  :

```
'is_visible_on_front'           => '1',
'is_searchable'                 => '1',
'is_visible_in_advanced_search' => '1',
'is_comparable'                 => '1',
'is_html_allowed_on_front'      => '1',
```

has anyone an idea?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your catalog only values are ignored (the ones in *catalog_eav_attribute* table).

My best guess is that your installer class *Welance_DBSetup_Model_Resource_Setup* is extended from *Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Setup* not from *Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Setup*.

Answer (score 0):

I have some code to create attribute programmatically.
There is function `createAttribute()`. You have to call it by giving parameters.  Hope this will help you

```
function createAttribute($code, $label, $attribute_type, $product_type, $attribute_set_name, $group_name )
{
    $_attribute_data = array(
        'attribute_code' => $code,
        'is_global' => '1',
        'frontend_input' => $attribute_type, //'boolean',
        'default_value_text' => '',
        'default_value_yesno' => '0',
        'default_value_date' => '',
        'default_value_textarea' => '',
        'is_unique' => '0',
        'is_required' => '0',
        'apply_to' => array($product_type), //array('grouped')
        'is_configurable' => '1',
        'is_searchable' => '1',
        'is_visible_in_advanced_search' => '1',
        'is_comparable' => '1',
        'is_used_for_price_rules' => '0',
        'is_wysiwyg_enabled' => '0',
        'is_html_allowed_on_front' => '1',
        'is_visible_on_front' => '1',
        'used_in_product_listing' => '0',
        'used_for_sort_by' => '0',
        'frontend_label' => array($label)
    );

    $model = Mage::getModel('catalog/resource_eav_attribute');

    if (!isset($_attribute_data['is_configurable'])) {
        $_attribute_data['is_configurable'] = 0;
    }
    if (!isset($_attribute_data['is_filterable'])) {
        $_attribute_data['is_filterable'] = 0;
    }
    if (!isset($_attribute_data['is_filterable_in_search'])) {
        $_attribute_data['is_filterable_in_search'] = 0;
    }

    if (is_null($model->getIsUserDefined()) || $model->getIsUserDefined() != 0) {
        $_attribute_data['backend_type'] = $model->getBackendTypeByInput($_attribute_data['frontend_input']);
    }

    $defaultValueField = $model->getDefaultValueByInput($_attribute_data['frontend_input']);
    if ($defaultValueField) {
      //  $_attribute_data['default_value'] = $this->getRequest()->getParam($defaultValueField);
    }

    $model->addData($_attribute_data);

    $model->setEntityTypeId(Mage::getModel('eav/entity')->setType('catalog_product')->getTypeId());
    $model->setIsUserDefined(1);
    try {
        $model->save();
        $setup = new Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Setup('core_setup');
            //-------------- add attribute to set and group

            $attribute_code = $code;

            $attribute_set_id=$setup->getAttributeSetId('catalog_product', $attribute_set_name);
            $attribute_group_id=$setup->getAttributeGroupId('catalog_product', $attribute_set_id, $group_name);
            $attribute_id=$setup->getAttributeId('catalog_product', $attribute_code);

            $setup->addAttributeToSet($entityTypeId='catalog_product',$attribute_set_id, $attribute_group_id, $attribute_id);

    } catch (Exception $e) { echo '<p>Sorry, error occured while trying to save the attribute. Error: '.$e->getMessage().'</p>'; }
}
```

Call function with parameters -

```
$attribute_set_name = "Default";
$group_name = "General";
createAttribute('technical_specs', "Technical Specs", "select", "simple", $attribute_set_name, $group_name); // use text instead of select if it is textbox
```